# cannot uninstall SharePoint Server 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I have installed SharePoint Server 2007 Entrprise. And I want to uninstall it. But each time I select to uninstall it, and at the beginning of the uninstall process (i.e. of the progress bar of uninstall process), the uninstall dialog will suddenly be terminated/disappeared (without any error message). From control panel, I can see the "Size" of installed SharePoint Server 2007 Entrprise is not available (seems very weird). I can also execute the SharePoint Central Administration from start menu -- so seems some SharePoint function still there in my machine?

Any ideas what is wrong and any solutions? Here is a screen snapshot of installed programs (with detailed information) of my control panel.

[image]

I am using Server 2008 x64 with SharePoint Server 2007 x64. The SharePoint Server 2007 Server x64 is trial edition (trial period expired) and it is why I want to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a few things before you can run the uninstall. Here is the list:

http://www.keirgordon.com/post/Uninstall-MOSS-2007.aspx

Comment: I am confused. If I have any existing web applications/sites running on SharePoint 2007 Server, I have to delete them manually before uninstall SharePoint Server 2007? If yes, do you have any official documents to prove it?

Comment: Thanks Shiraz! I have a related question here, appreciate if you could take a look.

http://serverfault.com/questions/80286/error-editing-sharepoint-page