# error editing SharePoint page

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Server x64 on Windows Server 2008 x64. I create a new SharePoint web application with a new site collection at the root of the web application. I select the template "publishing portal" for the site collection. I have also enabled anynomous access.

Now the basic function is fine, except that I do not know how to change the first front page (i.e. the page showed to end users who has not logged in yet) of the site. Here is a screen snapshot. Any ideas how to edit this page?

http://i33.tinypic.com/2hex08j.png

BTW: I have tried to edit the default.aspx after login, but after editing default.aspx, for a anonymous user, he/she could still see content like, how to remove such content for a anonymous user?

```
Enable anonymous access
You must enable anonymous access on the site collection for the forms authentication logon page to work from Office SharePoint Server. Contact your administrator to have anonymous access enabled in Central Administration and IIS.
Manage navigation
Change the navigation links in this site.
Go to master page gallery 
Change the page layouts and master page of this site collection.
Manage site content and structure
Reorganize content and structure in this site collection.
Set up multilingual support
Use the variations feature to manage multi-lingual sites and pages.
Add users to the Approvers and Members groups
Users in the Approvers group can publish pages, images, and documents in this site. Users in the Members group can create and edit pages, and they can upload images and documents, but they cannot publish the pages, images, or documents. Workflow is enabled in the Pages library, and content approval is enabled in the Documents and Images libraries.
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the answer to this, but you could try posting on http://www.sharepointoverflow.com, a stackexchange site for sharepoint.

Comment: Any other SharePoint discussion forums to recommend?